# How to structure a validation loop with multiple characters

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm struggling with learning validation loops in `Java`. I know how I need it to work but I can't seem to get it written.

If you select a character other than A, B, or C you receive an error

`while (selection != A && !=B && !=C )`

I also tried:

```java
       while (Selection != 'A' )
            {
            if (Selection != 'B') 
            else if (Selection != 'C')
            else System.out.println ("Invalid Entry. Please make another selestion");}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `while (selection != 'A' && selection != 'B' && selection != 'C')`

Comment: Although we says high level programming languages are "English-like", they are not really English. They have their syntax which must be followed. You cannot write `X not equal to A and not equal to B`. Instead, you have to write `X not equal to A and X not equal to B`. Because `!=` and `&&` are operators which take two `boolean` on left and right hand side and return a `boolean`. When writing `X != A && != B`, the right hand side of `&&` is not a boolean but an operator, the compiler doesn't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

What can help in more complex systems is a case statement:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter A, B or C: ");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();

    switch(input) {
        case "A":
          // do something for A
          break;
        case "B":
          // do something for B
          break;
        case "C":
          // do something for C
          break;
    }
}
```

Here I used an infinite loop. So for the user to get out of it, one of the options should break it. Therefore I'd add a quit option:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
endless: while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter A, B, C or quit: ");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();

    switch(input) {
        case "A":
          // do something for A
          break;
        case "B":
          // do something for B
          break;
        case "C":
          // do something for C
          break;
        case "quit":
          break endless; // break the while loop, not just the switch
    }
}
```

On the other side, if you just want to ensure you have one of the values A, B or C input and then continue with exactly that value, use

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = null;
endless: while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter A, B or C: ");
    input = scanner.nextLine();

    switch(input) {
        case "A":
        case "B":
        case "C":
            break endless;
    }
}
System.out.println("Thank you for choosing " + input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the new switch with arrow, without break and with comma separated case values:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
char answer = ' ';
while (answer == ' ') {
    System.out.println("Enter A, B, C or quit: ");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    switch (input) {
    case "A", "B", "C" ->
        answer = input.charAt(0);
    quit ->
        answer = 'q';
    default ->
        System.out.printf("Not A, B or C: '%s'.", input);
    }
}
if (answer == 'q') {
    System.exit();
}
```